# Send Ajax Request For Sending Post Data One Url to Another Url Without Getting CROS ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

-> Please Help Me To Solve The Problem

-> I Send Data To Another URL for Process Something And That Web Page is another Server and Different URL.

-> When Ever I Try To Send Post Data That time i Faced CROS Error i try many ways.

-> See My Code

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Another Non Https Url',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType:'application/json',
        data:{CompanyEmail:CompanyEmail,CompanyName:CompanyName,CompanyPhoneNumber:CompanyPhoneNumber,AccessToken:AccessToken},
        success: function(){
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS (meaning "Cross Origin Resource Sharing") is a server-side mechanism to allow exceptions in the so-called Same-Origin-Policy. Otherwise processing data from another origin is prevented.

You have to explicitly enable CORS for your client within your server.
This can't be fixed in your client-side jQuery-Code.

PHP-side you are able to activate CORS for all clients by using

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

though.